# OptaPlanner: Squaring the match weight score - when and why?

Tags: optaplanner, scoring

I have noticed in some of the OP examples that the match weight is squared, for example here: https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/b1ad3d90773be5194979246c4c19b4a141efdf85/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/taskassigning/score/TaskAssigningConstraintProvider.java#L55

```
private Constraint minimizeMakespan(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(Employee.class)
                .penalize(BendableScore.ofSoft(BENDABLE_SCORE_HARD_LEVELS_SIZE, BENDABLE_SCORE_SOFT_LEVELS_SIZE, 1, 1),
                        employee -> employee.getEndTime() * employee.getEndTime())
                .asConstraint("Minimize makespan, latest ending employee first");
    }
```

I understand the reason for having a score function is to minimise / prevent score traps, but am wondering when you would consider squaring the score? Are there any rules of thumb when deciding this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of that is to tell the solver that 1 violation of the constraint is much more acceptable than 2, and 2 is much more acceptable than 3 violations, 4, 5... It is a penalty that gets worse the further you get away from the target value - so as the difference from the target value grows, the solver has much less incentive to pick that solution.

You may also want to see [our discussion of fairness](https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2017/02/03/FormulaForMeasuringUnfairness.html), which is tangentially related to this.